# ¿Cómo instalar tensorflow 2 para que pille CUDA v11.2?

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow, cuda, gpu

estoy intentando instalar tensorflow, pero no soy capaz de que pille mi GPU, que es una nvidia rtx 2080 super, mi versión de CUDA es la 11.2 y estoy usando tensorflow 2.3.0, utilizo anaconda para gestionar todas las dependencias de python y tengo una versión de python 3.8.5

Al ejecutar:

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

me retorna false y si ejecuto:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

me retorna un array vacío, mientras que con CPU en lugar de GPU, me dice que el tipo de dispositivo que está usando es la CPU, pues bien, como puedo instalar o configurar tensorflow para que funcione bien con mi GPU?? no soy capaz de hacer que detecte mi gpu para poder utilizarla, y he seguido guías que he encontrado pero no logro sacar nada en claro, ¿alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto para poder empezar a trabajar con mis algoritmos de inteligencia artificial? Muchas gracias, por cierto, estoy utilizando windows 10, de nuevo muchas gracias.

Comment: Estás seguro de que Tensorflow 2 funciona con CUDA 11 ? https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Comment: Entonces, si no funciona con cuda 11.2, que puedo hacer??

Comment: Pues no estoy seguro, pero aquí hablan de alternativas... https://github.com/houseofai/tf4cuda

Comment: Te sugiero purgar (eliminar) todo y seguir las [instrucciones de instalación de Tensorlfow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)

Comment: Ya lo intente pero nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recientemente estuve instalando Tensorflow GPU en mi Windows con Anaconda y también tuve problemas para su instalación con Anaconda y Cuda 11.

Las conclusiones que obtuve fueron que Tensorflow no soporta Cuda 11 (porque los dll que intenta importar son de la versión 10.1 (cudar64_101.dll por ejemplo).

Los pasos que acabé siguiendo fueron, de forma resumida:

- Instalar Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community porque, según leí, es conveniente disponer del compilador de C++ de VS, concretamente el módulo "Desarrollo para el escritorio con C++".
- Instalar CUDA 10.1 (sobreescribiendo CUDA 11, pero ojo, no sobreescribas los Drivers de Nvidia). Desde aquí puedes descargarlo: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2
- Descargar cuDNN 7.6.5 para CUDA 10.1. Desde aquí puedes descargarlo: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive
- Modificar la variable PATH del sistema tal y como dice Tensorflow en su web (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu?hl=es-419). cuDNN, para que sea igual que en la web, lo tendrás que descomprimir en C:\tools...

Ahora, con Anaconda, mejor desde la terminal (Anaconda Prompt):

- Creas un nuevo entorno con la versión de Python que quieras usar, si es 3.8, pues:
  (base) C:\user\usuario> conda create --name NOMBRE python=3.8
- Lo activas
- Yo instalé, porque lo necesitaba, ipykernel y Jupyter Notebook
- Instalas tensorflow. La ubicación del paquete la encuentras aquí: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=es-419
  Si es Tensorflow GPU para Python 3.8 en Windows, sería el siguiente enlace a usar:
  (NOMBRE) C:\user\usuario> python -m install ENLACE
  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
- Ya debería estar instalado Tensorflow

Ahora si abres el intérprete de python e importas tensorflow, deberías poder ver la salida esperada de la función:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Espero que te haya funcionado